# How to extract list of Google fit compatible devices?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, device

how do I extract a list of google fit app compatible devices? I'm releasing an app that relies on the Google fit app and want to exclude devices that don't support google fit.

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to the device that doesn't support Google Fit, by checking the internet, you will find here a [thread](https://www.ismartliving.net/articles/google-fit-compatible-devices-apps/) giving the Google Fit Compatible Device and Application. So the device and the application that doesn't mention on this thread means that they are the devices that are not supported by the Google FIT. You can also check this [one](https://www.wareable.com/google/the-best-google-fit-compatible-apps-and-devices).